# Editable value in Case (Ilogic based on Vb)

Tags: vb.net, autodesk-inventor

I have a part that varies depending on the diameter of the rope. Rope ranges and geometrical parameters are defined. But one parameter must be editable. I want to be offered a set of default values, but I could, at my discretion, be able to change the parameter I need or leave it as it is.
  Here is the piece of code:

```
Select Case dk
    Case "From 3 to 3,7"
        B = 6
        B1 = 13
        hк = 5
        R = 2
    Case "From 3,7 to 4,6" 
        B = 8
        B1 = 15
        hк = 6
        R = 2.5
    Case "From 4,6 to 5,6" 
        B = 9
        B1 = 16
        hк = 7
        R = 3
    Case "From 5,6 to 7,2" 
        B = 12
        B1 = 19
        hк = 9
        R = 4
    End Select
```

The value to be changed is B1. In fact, this value should not be less than or equal to B. Therefore, I would be happy with a solution where B1 varies in the range.
  Thank you in advance for your help in this matter.

Comment: Why is this question tagged VBA and VB.NET? Read the descriptions of those tags. They both state that they are not to be used for questions on the other. Work out what language you're using and use tags relevant to that language only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two parameters more. B1max (max value for B1) and B1req (requested value for B1). In your code set B1max instead of B1. Parameter B1req can be set to any value by the user or another iLogic code.

For parameter B1 use expression "min(max(B;B1req);B1max)". Now the B1 parameter value can only be from range B to B1max and equals to B1req when possible.

```
Select Case dk
Case 3 to 3.7 '"From 3 to 3,7"
    B = 6
    B1max = 13
    hk = 5
    R = 2
Case 3.7 To 4.6 '"From 3,7 to 4,6" 
    B = 8
    B1max = 15
    hk = 6
    R = 2.5
Case 4.6 To 5.6 '"From 4,6 to 5,6" 
    B = 9
    B1max = 16
    hk = 7
    R = 3
Case 5.6 To 7.2 '"From 5,6 to 7,2" 
    B = 12
    B1max = 19
    hk = 9
    R = 4
Case Else
    Logger.Error("Parameter 'dk' is out of range")
End Select

Logger.Debug("B = " & B)
Logger.Debug("B1max = " & B1max)
Logger.Debug("hk = " & hk)
Logger.Debug("R = " & R)
```

[image]